# Records are missing while using Rewrite_Tag filter in fluentbit output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

I am using fluentbit with Fargate with mount volume where logs input is from stdout and using rewrite tag to separate access and application logs to two different indices, When I am using single index all the logs are parsing fine and everthing working fine, but when I want to separate the logs the rewrite tag filter is not working.

Am I missing anything? when I tried fluentbit conf with tail input with the below logs manually copy pasting and patterns to file output they are differentiating the logs as expected in local machine.
while using fluentbit with fargate rewrite tag is not working as expected.
Note : the taskdefinition which i am using for this configuration will be in Running state for 1 minute only, Will does effects anything with log processor to take time for rewrite_tag ? But the same thing is working fine for single index without rewrite_tag.

````
**fluenbit.conf**
[SERVICE]
    Log_Level debug
    Parsers_File /mnt/parser-custom.conf
[FILTER]
    Name parser
    Match **
    Parser app_logs
    Parser access_logs
    Key_Name log
    Reserve_Data True
[FILTER]
    Name rewrite_tag
    Match *.*
    Rule $Class ^((?!\[io\.undertow\.accesslog\]).)*$ apptag true
    Rule $Class ^.*\[io\.undertow\.accesslog\].*$ acstag true
    Emitter_Name re_emitted
[OUTPUT]
    Name      es
    Match     apptag
    Host      vpc-#####.es.amazonaws.com
    Port      443
    Type      _doc
    AWS_Region  us-east-2
    AWS_AUTH   On
    tls        On
    Index      fb-applogs
[OUTPUT]
    Name      es
    Match     acstag
    Host      vpc-#####.es.amazonaws.com
    Port      443
    Type      _doc
    AWS_Region  us-east-2
    AWS_AUTH   On
    tls        On
    Index      fb-acclogs
    ```



**parser-custom.conf**
[PARSER]
    Name    app_logs
    Format  regex
    #Regex ^(?<JBTime>\[\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}\])(?<App>\-[^\s\]]+)\[(?<Severity>[\s\S]*)\](?<Class>[^\s\(]+)\((?<Thread>[\s\S]*)\)(?<Message>[\s\S]*)$
    Regex ^(?<JBTime>\[\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}\])(?<App>\-[^\s\]]+)\[(?<Severity>[\s\S]*)\](?<Class>\S+)\((?<Thread>\w+)\)(?<Message>[\s\S]*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L

[PARSER]
    Name    access_logs
    Format  regex
    Regex   ^\[(?<Apachetime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3})\](?<App>-\w{9})\[(?<Severity>[\s\S]*)\](?<Class>[^\s]+)\((?<subject>[^\s]+ [^\s]+)\)\W{2}(?<date>[^ ]*) (?<Time>[^ ]*) (?<Host>[^ ]*) \W \W (?<Method>[^\s]+)(?: +(?<URL>[^ ]*) +\S*) (?<Code>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<Referer>[^\"]*))" "(?<Agent>[^\"]*)" (?<Res>[\s\S]*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L



**Sample Logs :** 
***Application Log* :**
               [2023-03-20 07:34:02,883]-JOB[DEBUG][org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner](main)[ 10.125.72.101]Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/jboss/achjob/achjob.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/ach-core-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com//ach/core/inb/helper/OutbUpdateHelper.class]

**AccessLog : **
               [2023-06-12 11:39:20,490]-APPNAME[INFO ][io.undertow.accesslog](XNIO-1 task-1){[]}2023-06-12 11-39-20 127.0.0.1 - - POST /psm/inter/receive_custnsfer/accept HTTP/1.1 200 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2" 12342 3.718
````

Comment: I am missing the INPUT part. Can you just create two input tail sections one for each file and give them the right tag from beginning? So you dont need to rewrite the tag. Rewrite tag is great but I have the feeling it has problems with higher load. If you want to use rewrite tag can you first just use one rule and see if it works.